# loadURL and javascript on iOs - Cannot pass strings

Tags: ios, air

I am encountering a very stragne bug, i am trying to call javascript from AIR like this

`this.webView.loadURL( 'javascript:alert(5)' );` -- This works

`this.webView.loadURL( 'javascript:alert("hello there")' );` -- This is not working

I am not able to pass strings, in any function. I am not sure why this is happening and it is driving me insane. It works correctly in Android though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT: after spending sometime tweaking it seems to be the space. alert("hello") works fine alert("hello there") doesnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I found it.

You cannot pass whitespaces. You can in Android and Desktop - but no, the glorious iOs refuses to digest such an advanced entity.

So you must encode your whitespaces in strings and make sure that there will be no stray whitespace in your functiond declration

for example

```
this.webView.loadURL("javascript:test('hey__there')"); //will work
```

while

```
this.webView.loadURL("javascript: test('hey__there')"); //this won't

this.webView.loadURL("javascript:test( 'hey__there' )"); //this won't
```

Good luck

Comment: Were you able to use `javascript:` on iOS?

Comment: Yes I was able to use it properly (it was the whitespaces that caused the problem). Do you need any help with it?

Comment: Thank you, no. It's odd because I was reading this:http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/07/flex-mobile-invoking-javascript-in-a-stagewebview/ Which seems to suggest you can't call javascript methods directly. Was wondering.

Comment: What I am trying to do, though, is get the value a function in JavaScript returns back into the main application if that is possible.

Comment: No it is very possible to call javascript function, you just have to make sure that there are no whitespaces in the loadURL argument. Also it is possible to grab the value that a JS function returned. To do that, since there is no ExternalInterface available, you will have to...

Comment: add listeners to the webView, with addEventListener( LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, CALLBACK );   and  LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE   then make sure that in CALLBACK the following is true. e.type == "locationChanging"

Comment: and grab the url of the webview like this  unescape((e as LocationChangeEvent).location). In JS you will ahve to modify the url, (by tweaking window.location.href,  the hash alone is not enough)

Comment: While this will work on Android, it will fail on iOs. In order to make it work you will have to modify the "whole" url, from the protocol level ( window.location.href =  "data://" + message + "?args=" + moreData; //works fine )

Comment: I hope I was of help, I will try to write a small tutorial within the weekend

Comment: Hm, that's clever. I don't know what size limitations iOS has for URLs, but what I am trying to pass back is quite a bit of HTML code. Also, in the mean time I found this: http://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/. Looks promising, but I'm not sure how well supported it actually is. Thank you.